# malloc global array in functions

Tags: c

**SOLVED**

Why is `malloc`ing `W[51]` in `load51()` messing with `W[50]` contents?

```
typedef struct qword { short chap, chapPos, Sentence, nbLetters, gVal; char *L;} qword;

qword *W[73];

main() { load50(); load51(); }
load50() {    // This function is generated by a script that reads a txt file
  qword w;
  short chap = 50, p = 0;
  W[chap] = (qword *) malloc(376*sizeof(qword));

  // Fill every single qword in W[50]:
  //* (sentence 0, word 1)
  w.Sentence = 0; w.chapPos = ++p;
  { char B[] = {1, 12, 12}; w.L = B; }; w.nbLetters = 3; w.gVal = 21; W[chap][p] = w;
  // //* (sentence 0, word 2) ... 
}
load51() { 
  W[51] = (qword *) malloc(365*sizeof(qword)); 
  // Then fill every single qword in W[51], like in load50()
}
```

`load50()` works just fine, and everything is as expected, and `W[50]` is perfect.

`printf`ing `W[50][375].L` shows it is altered after `load51()` is called. Notice that `W[51]` is ~10 `qword`s smaller than `W[50]`.

`W` is a global variable, so I don't see the need to pass a `***qword` to `load` functions and call `load(&W)`.

Same problem under Cygwin (GCC) & Visual Studio.

---

### Solution

Don't use a limited scope `B`, `malloc` instead

`w.L = malloc(3); w.L[0] = 1; w.L[1] = 12; w.L[2] = 12;`

Comment: For arrays, prefer `calloc` to `malloc`. And pass the `sizeof` an element of the array. Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). Use a debugger (e.g. `gdb`, its `watch`points are very useful) and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and [instrumentation options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html). Beware of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (and you might have some, perhaps elsewhere). You probably don't show enough code to get help. You should make some MVCE

Comment: *How* do you "fill every single qword in W[50]"? And the same for `W[51]`? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: Do you allocate memory for every `char *L`?

Comment: I can't see much wrong with what you have posted. An array of qword pointers, and you load a couple of them with mallocs.  I suspect an out-of-bounds UB, so the like, in whatever you have not posted.  Also 'qword' is not a very good identifier for the type - it gets confused with an Intel QWORD, also confusing is the same identifier for both declaration and definition in yuor typedef :(

Comment: I just edited to show how W is filled. The load functions are generated by a script that reads a txt file and builds them to fill W with the file structure (chapters, sentences, words, and letters in L). A letter is coded with its alphabetic order (L is really an array of bytes). And no, no out of bound issues (unless load51 is shrinking W[50]). I've done a thousand printfs since yesterday evening..

Comment: 'char B[] = {1, 12, 12}; w.L = B;' - think about what you are doing, there, especially about the lifetime of B.

Comment: @Martin James : yes, B is a throw away variable, it doesn't survive the closing "}", which is what I want. After load50() is called, all words in W[50] are correctly filled (I can print all 375 of them).

Comment: @ExpertNoob1 But `W[50][0].L` is a pointer to `B`.  If `B` has been thrown away, then `W[50][0].L` is also no good.  If you're unlucky, trying to print it (especially very soon after) might *seem* to work, but it's still undefined behavior which will almost certainly bite you later.

Comment: *"which is what I want"* Do you mind elaborate on that? Your question is about why `W[50][375].L` (a pointer to a no more existing local variable) is altered...

Comment: Downvoted. Question is still unclear after edit, code is confusing, and there is no [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). OP should learn to use a debugger and other tools and [read about **undefined behavior**](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch : it was enough for Martin to pinpoint the problem origin anyways. Your idea to use gbd is great, I should have thought of that.

Comment: For readability use `int8_t`  or `uint8_t` (not `char`) for small 8 bits integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this block in your function:

```
{ char B[] = {1, 12, 12}; w.L = B; }
```

Here the variable `B` is ***local inside the block***. Once the block ends (with the `}`) the variable goes out of scope and cease to exist, leaving you with a stray pointer.

Dereferencing this stray pointer leads to *undefined behavior*.

Perhaps you should be allocating memory for `w.L` dynamically, and the *copy* the contents of `B` into the allocated memory (remembering to `free` the memory when you free the structure).

---

On an unrelated note, I recommend you use `char` for actual characters only. If you want small signed integers I suggest you use `int8_t` instead. It's just an alias for `unsigned char` but it tells the readers of your code that you're just storing small integers instead of characters. Such semantic information makes programs easier to maintain in the future.

Comment: Thank you Martin James & Some programmer dude. That was the issue. Problem solved. I actually define qword with *byte* *L, with byte == unsigned char (to minimize memory consumption, it's just an index between 1 and 22).